# Defined tabular cells with different sizes

Tags: tables, multicolumn

I'm trying to have a table where some cells are aligned and some are not.
In the following figure I tried to define cell "Offering working unit" with a 6 cm.

[image]

However, it is larger than that as the cell of the next row "Ch total theoretical" has 6 cm. Also, "Offering working unit" text is now trying to 6 cm but its | with "Refs.:" is not.

How do I fix it to really represent 6 cm with "|"? 
How do I control its size to be any value I would want?

My code follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\bf\large\centering
\begin{tabular}{|p{6cm}|c|p{5.4cm}|}\hline 
\centering    CODE: & \multicolumn{2}{p{8cm}|}{COMPONENT USE:} \\
     & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{}\\ 
     & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{}\\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|p{6cm}|}{OFFERING WORKING UNIT:} & REFS.: \\
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{} & \\ 
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{} & \\ \hline
\centering CH TOTAL THEORETICAL: &\centering CH PARTIAL: & {\centering CH TOTAL:} \\
 & &\\
 & \hfill&\\\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an inner, nested `tabular` with desired width:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\bf\large\centering
\begin{tabular}{|p{6cm}|c|p{5.4cm}|}\hline
\centering    CODE: & \multicolumn{2}{p{8cm}|}{COMPONENT USE:} \\[1.5cm] \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l}{%
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}p{7cm}|}
OFFERING WORKING UNIT:\\[2cm]
\end{tabular}}
& REFS.: \\ \hline
\centering CH TOTAL THEORETICAL: & CH PARTIAL: & {\centering CH TOTAL:} \\[2cm]\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is a macro for the same:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcommand{\uglycell}[2][6cm]{%
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}p{#1}|}
#2\\[2cm]
\end{tabular}
}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\bf\large\centering
\begin{tabular}{|p{6cm}|c|p{5.4cm}|}\hline
\centering    CODE: & \multicolumn{2}{p{8cm}|}{COMPONENT USE:} \\[1.5cm] \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l}{\uglycell[7cm]{OFFERING WORKING UNIT:}}
& REFS.: \\ \hline
\centering CH TOTAL THEORETICAL: & CH PARTIAL: & {\centering CH TOTAL:} \\[2cm]\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

But yikes! why do you want such an ugly table? :)

---

Old answer

I think I didn't understand properly. Is it like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\bf\large\centering
\begin{tabular}{|p{6cm}|c|p{5.4cm}|}\hline
\centering    CODE: & \multicolumn{2}{p{8cm}|}{COMPONENT USE:} \\[1.5cm] \hline
\raggedright OFFERING WORKING UNIT: & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{REFS.:} \\[2cm] \hline
\centering CH TOTAL THEORETICAL: & CH PARTIAL: & {\centering CH TOTAL:} \\[1.5cm] \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Instead of using two blank rows for extra space, you can use `\\[2cm]\hline`. change 2cm as you wish.

[image]

Comment: Sorry the confusion. The value in 6cm `\multicolumn{2}{|p{6cm}|}{OFFERING WORKING UNIT:}` is arbitrary. If I change it to 7cm it still won't change the place of "|". I want to control every cell size. Does this make sense?

Comment: @MarcKees Things are not very flexible here. When you say `\multicolumn` text will follow the width you are giving but the vertical line will appear at the next stop. You can use a nested `tabular` instead.

Comment: So inside every row I use a new tabular?

Comment: @MarcKees See the update. Whenever you want such odd widths, yes. You may even make a macro. Let me add it.

Comment: @MarcKees macro added.